# how to inherit listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, inheritance, .net-4.0

I have a listview that I want to inherit I am using most of the code exactly in the same listviews but I would like to make one generic listview so I could customize it for each list as I need.

I am using WPF and C#.

what is the best way to it?

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this:

```
class MyListView<T> : ListView
```

Comment: no, I have serverl lists in my application. and most of them has the same feature (some have more) and I would like to make one generic list that the itemsource will be different and in each list it will act as it should. (other events, other context menu, ETC.) how can it be done?

Comment: It's a bit confusing. Can you post some pseudo-code of how you would like this to be done?

Comment: @user1032412: So you can use `Teacher` or `Student` in place of `T` in the generic subclass above. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: He probably wants lists of Teacher to behave otherwise than lists of Students, am I right?

Comment: BTW: student and teacher are inherit from the same base class and I want that the itemsource will be observercollection of of base class

Comment: @M.Schenkel :  you are right.. same gui but different functionality

Comment: I guess your misinterpreting the functionality of List<T>. T is a generic type, which means you can basically put everything in this list (Teachers or Students). Can you clearly explain what you are trying to accomplish? Maybe I can help you with a suitable solution.

Comment: @M.Schenkel : I have two listviews one with teachers and one with students. they two different observercollevtions. I Have two controls for each of the lists. the functionality of the usercontorls are almost the same but I have some changes in each of it. I can remove teacher and remove student (add, change name, etc.) but, I have stuff that I can do in the student that I cant do in the teacher (like change grade) and opposite (change teacher class) so I want to make base listview that have the common vunctionallity and inherit for each class I want to extend. is it possible?

Comment: The functionality you mention, is functionality for a single instance of a Teacher / Student. I dont see why you should extend the List. For example, you said 'functions like ChangeGrade()'. I dont see why you want that function on a list of Students, rather than on the Student object itself. You can have a List<Student> and a List<Teacher>, thats what the List<T> is for. With some LINQ you can get a specific student and change their grade: List<Student>().First(s => s.Name = 'John Doe').ChangeGrade(10);. Does this make any sense to you, or do you want another example?

Comment: Hi, I will give you another example. I have those two listviews. and I have some items group and I would like to change one of the items group.. by drag and drop or by something in each item context menu. but changing group in teacher and in student are not the same